# PHP url execute

Tags: php, curl

I want to update icecast server metadata info, everything works great if I enter it manually into the browser like this:

```
http://IPADDRESS:PORT/admin/metadata?mount=/live&mode=updinfo&song=ARTIST+SONG+NAME
```

I get XML response that metadata is successfully updated and it really is if I check live stream (even the iTunes pops out with the song info).

The problem is that I made a php script that should using cURL execute this same URL but I tried numeruos ways and solutions and non of them works. Can anyone help me? How can I execute this URL in the php script?

Thank you!

This is the code in my php that should execute the URL to update metadata but it does not work:

```
    $url = "http://IPADDRESS:PORT/admin/metadata?mount=/live&mode=updinfo&song=".urlencode($params)."";
file_put_contents($file2, $url);
$agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

I even created help so that URL gets saved in .txt file and it gets generated OK. If I copy it and manually enter it in browser metadata gets changed, but automatically trough php script it won't. I also tried with http authentication for icecast and won't work, when I'm entering URL manually I don't need to authenticate for changing metadata.

I really don't know what else to do.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: checked the curl errors?

Comment: Hey, I got "Couldn't connect to host". I assume that URL is wrong?

Comment: You are explicitly specifying a port which means you are probably using some exotic port which is not allowed to pass the operating system firewall (probably `iptables`).

Comment: But if I copy URL into the browser (manually) it runs ok. Port is of icecast server and it's open for listening for sure.

Comment: [icecast doc](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/admin-interface.html)

Here is icecast documentation where is the link structure for updating metadata and I'm simply following the rules. When I enter it manually in browser it works, but from php cURL it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not have the permission of changing meta data of your Icecast Radio because it does **NOT** have any username and password. You can make the URL query work in your browser because you simply give username and password before. You can send username and password using `CURLOPT_USERPWD`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
```

Comment: I added it like this:

`$username = 'source';
$password = 'password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$errors = curl_error($ch);
file_put_contents($file2, $errors);
curl_close($ch);`